# custom navigation bar with images once for all views swift

Tags: image, swift, uinavigationbar

I've added the navigation bar in storyboard by embedding in the `navigation controller`.

I want to custom the navigation bar to have an image at left as `backBarButtonItem`, an image in the center as `Title` and an image at right. The navigation layout is going to be the same in all my views.

How can I custom it once for all?

The navigation bar is like this : [image]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass the `UIViewController` and set the required parameters in the `viewWillAppear` function of the custom view controller class

```
class CustomViewController : UIViewController
{
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
         self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = // Custom
         // Set title and all your settings.
    }
}
```

Set `CustomViewController` as the `Class` property of your `ViewControllers` in the your storyboard. Also use `CustomViewController` as base class in your swift view controller files.

[image]

Comment: sorry, I can't get it. If I have to use `CustomViewController` in all my view controllers, which means that I can't custom my navigation bar once? I mean like in `AppDelegate.swift`I can use `UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()`to change it for all my views.

Comment: if you use the CustomViewController as view controller, you can set a custom backbutton easily